# Neural network from scratch - predict single example

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

Here is a neural network I've modified from Coursera Deep Learning Specialization to train on a dataset containing a flattened array of training data :

```
%reset -s -f

import numpy as np
import math

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def initialize_with_zeros(dim):

    w = np.zeros(shape=(dim, 1))
    b = 0

    return w, b

X = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0] , [1,1,1,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1]])
Y = np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,1]])

X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T
Y = Y.reshape(Y.shape[0], -1).T

print('X shape' , X.shape)
print('Y shape' , Y.shape)

b = 1
w, b = initialize_with_zeros(4)

def propagate(w, b, X, Y) : 

    m = X.shape[1]

    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)  # compute activation
    cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A) + (1 - Y) * (np.log(1 - A)))  # compute cost
    dw = (1./m)*np.dot(X,((A-Y).T))
    db = (1./m)*np.sum(A-Y, axis=1)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost

propagate(w , b , X , Y)

learning_rate = .001
costs = []

def optimize(w , b, X , Y) :
    for i in range(2):

        grads, cost = propagate(w=w, b=b, X=X, Y=Y)

        dw = grads["dw"]
        db = grads["db"]

        w = w - learning_rate*dw
        b = b -  learning_rate*db

        if i % 100 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)

    return w , b

w , b = optimize(w , b , X , Y)

def predict(w, b, X):

    m = 6
    Y_prediction = np.zeros((1,m))
#     w = w.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)

    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):

        if A[0, i] >= 0.5:
            Y_prediction[0, i] = 1

        else:
            Y_prediction[0, i] = 0

    return Y_prediction

predict(w , b, X)
```

This works as expected but I'm struggling to predict a single example.

If I use :

```
predict(w , b, X[0])
```

returns error :

```
ValueError: shapes (6,4) and (6,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 6 (dim 0)
```

How to re-arrange matrix operation in order to predict a single instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
predict(w, b, X[:1])
```

It seems like you `predict` function expects `X` to be 2-d, when passing only one `X` it should have a singleton second dimension (i.e., shape=(6,1)) rather than being a single dimension (i.e., shape=(6,)).

Comment: predict(w , b , X[:1]) returns error 'ValueError: shapes (6,4) and (1,6) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)' I then tried reshaping to your suggestion (6,1) : predict(w, b, X[:1].reshape((6, 1))) but error 'ValueError: shapes (6,4) and (6,1) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 6 (dim 0)' is returned.

Comment: @blue-sky why do you hard coded `m=6` in your `prediction` function? if I understand correctly, `m` is the number of examples you have with dim=4 for each. You need to set your dimensions straight in `prediction` and then verify that the `X` you try to predict is of dim=4 and not dim=6.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that predict expect to be called on a batch of data of shape `... * bs`. In order to predict on a single element you can create a batch of size 1 using `np.expand_dims` :

```
predict(w, b, np.expand_dims(X[0], axis=1)
```

should work.